# Garbage collection in AWS lambda java 8

Tags: aws-lambda, java-8, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I have an AWS lambda application written in Java 8. Recently I was seeing the memory was reaching to almost 95%. Then I increased the memory by almost 100MB, and then this issue was not there. I wanted to understand one thing here, like in other applications like ECS or any general JAVA application, the GC comes into play once the memory reaches approx 90%, does that same behavior come up in case of lambdas as well ?

Or, is there any other way of memory cleanup happening in lambda applications written in java 8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable logs if you want to be sure how it is working:

Prior to Java 9, including Java 8, you configure the garbage collection logging as follows:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

Java 11 uses the Unified Logging System (JEP 158 and JEP 271) which has been introduced in Java 9. Logging can be configured with the environment variable:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xlog:gc+metaspace,gc+heap,gc:stdout:time,tags
```

**The lifecycle of a JVM application on AWS Lambda**

> Let’s first revisit the lifecycle of the AWS Lambda Java runtime and
> its JVM:

- A Lambda function is invoked.
- AWS Lambda launches an execution context. This is a temporary runtime environment based on the configuration settings you provide, like permissions, memory size, and environment variables.
- AWS Lambda creates a new log stream in Amazon CloudWatch Logs for each instance of the execution context.
- The execution context initializes the JVM and your handler’s code.

> AWS Lambda maintains the execution context for some time in
> anticipation of another Lambda function invocation. In effect, the
> service freezes the execution context after a Lambda function
> completes. It thaws the execution context when the Lambda function is
> invoked again if AWS Lambda chooses to reuse it.
>
> **During invocations, the JVM also maintains garbage collection as
> usual. Outside of invocations, the JVM and its maintenance processes
> like garbage collection are also frozen.**

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-monitoring-the-java-virtual-machine-garbage-collection-on-aws-lambda/